# WebAPI giving 404 on server

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, autofac

This has been asked a million times but....

I have a WebAPI. It works on my local machine running IIS. But after deploying to server, it fails.

Things I have tried:

Added

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

Set handlers to

```
<remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Add json as MIME type

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>
```

Routing is mapped as

```
// Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Startup file:

```
public static void ConfigureContainer(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        var options = CreateCorsOptions();
        app.UseCors(options);

        // Get your HttpConfiguration.
        config = new HttpConfiguration();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);

        RegistererWebApi(builder, config);

        // Register dependencies, then...
        var container = builder.Build();
        var webApiResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = webApiResolver;

        // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST. This also adds
        // Autofac-injected middleware registered with the container.
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);

    }

private static void RegistererWebApi(ContainerBuilder builder, HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Register your Web API controllers.
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // OPTIONAL: Register the Autofac filter provider.
        //builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my full WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Register the WebAPI. Remove Xml formatter (OPnly using JSON). Add filters. Set Routing
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="config"></param>
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //Enable cross origin requests
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://local.isos.com,htt://dev.isos.mydelphic.com,http://qa.isos.mydelphic.com,http://localhost/", headers: "*", methods: "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        // Web API configuration and services
        // Remove the XML formatter
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        json.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;

        config.Filters.Add(new UnhandledExceptionFilter());

        config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CacheCow.Server.CachingHandler(config));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
```

**UPDATE2**

Here is how I register my controllers with Autofac

```
private static void RegistererWebApi(ContainerBuilder builder, HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Register your Web API controllers.
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());            
    }
```

And here is my controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("providers")]
public class ProviderController : BaseApiController
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="requestDispatcher">Dispatcher gets injected by Ioc</param>
    public ProviderController(IRequestDispatcher requestDispatcher)
        : base(requestDispatcher)
    { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a list of all providers outside the Philipines
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns an action result regarding the state of the request. Returns a 200 containing the list of providers. Returns a 404 is no results are found.</returns>
    [Route("",Name="Providers")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string sort = "ProviderName", int page = 1, int pageSize = 10)
    {
        var query = new GetProviders();
        // Populate the view model by calling the appropriate handler
        var providers = await RequestDispatcher.DispatchAsync<GetProviders, ProvidersResponse>(query);
        if (providers == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var totalCount = providers.Count;
        var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalCount / pageSize);

        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(Request);

        //Route name
        var prevLink = page > 1 ? urlHelper.Link("Providers",
        new
        {
            page = page - 1,
            pageSize = pageSize,
            sort = sort
        }) : "";

        var nextLink = page < totalPages ? urlHelper.Link("Providers",
        new
        {
            page = page + 1,
            pageSize = pageSize,
            sort = sort
        }) : "";


        var paginationHeader = new
        {
            currentPage = page,
            pageSize = pageSize,
            totalCount = totalCount,
            totalPages = totalPages,
            previousPageLink = prevLink,
            nextPageLink = nextLink
        };

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("X-Pagination", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paginationHeader));

        return Ok(providers);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you defining route?

Comment: In WebApiConfig.Register. And I'm really just using attribute routes.

Comment: On which/how/type of API call?

Comment: Can you show the controller that isn't found? Also, is the controller in the same assembly as the Startup class or are you doing some sort of "scanning" to dynamically load "plug-ins?"

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're using OWIN, not the older-style singleton `GlobalConfiguration`... yet you're setting the dependency resolver on `GlobalConfiguration`.

[One of the common errors when using OWIN is to try to set the `GlobalConfiguration` dependency resolver.](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration)

Try setting `config.DependencyResolver` instead. [Check the docs for example/explanation.](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration)

Comment: I did need this, but it did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was a configuration setting. On the server, which is an older server, although still running IIS7, you need to explicitly tell IIS to look for an OWIN start up class:

```
<appSettings>  
  <add key="owin:appStartup"          vaue="yourproject.startup" />       
</appSettings>
```